# Amazon AWS login error on port 443

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-s3

I am trying to login to my Amazon AWS instance and I am getting this error.

```
        debug1: Connection established.
        debug1: identity file VOIPSystemServer.pem type -1
        debug1: identity file VOIPSystemServer.pem-cert type -1
        debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
        debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
        debug1: ssh_exchange_identification: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">

        debug1: ssh_exchange_identification: <html><head>

        debug1: ssh_exchange_identification: <title>400 Bad Request</title>

        debug1: ssh_exchange_identification: </head><body>

        debug1: ssh_exchange_identification: <h1>Bad Request</h1>

        debug1: ssh_exchange_identification: <p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />

        debug1: ssh_exchange_identification: </p>

        debug1: ssh_exchange_identification: <hr>

        debug1: ssh_exchange_identification: <address>Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at ip-172-31-20-234.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal Port 80</address>

        debug1: ssh_exchange_identification: </body></html>

        ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

I have changed the port to 443, but I cannot login at all. I do not recall putting the HTTP server on port 443, so is this fixable?

Comment: Why would you try to use port 443 (SSL) instead of port 22 (SSH)?

Comment: I was behind an Academic proxy that blocks port 22.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED, I re-booted the server instance and it started working again. Sorry to post a redundant question. Not sure what the problem was, but an instance reboot was the solution.